How to construct distinct date ranges from a set of ranges in sql
I have a table with a boolean field I care about, along with the date ranges those fields are relevant. These date ranges can be overlapping, can be entirely interior to other date ranges, and can have gaps.
I only care about rows where the boolean field is true but I need to construct non-overlapping date ranges so I can sensibly join back to my data without creating duplicate records.
i.e. my data may look like:
user | is_relevant | from_date  | to_date    | description
-----|-------------|------------|------------|-------------
1    | true        | 2024-01-01 | 2024-02-01 | month of january
1    | true        | 2024-01-02 | 2024-01-03 | subset of january
1    | true        | 2024-01-15 | 2024-02-15 | mid-jan to mid-feb
1    | true        | 2024-03-01 | 2024-04-01 | distinct date range

I need to get to a table with two rows, one from 2024-01-01 to 2024-02-15 and another from 2024-03-01 to 2024-04-01.
Any help at all would be appreciated. If it makes a difference I'm running this in spark SQL, but a PySpark solution is fine.

This is a classic gaps-and-islands problem.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    col,
    collect_list,
    struct,
    row_number,
    last,
    min,
    max,
    when,
    lit,
    sum,
)
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MergeIntervals").getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [
    (1, True, "2024-01-01", "2024-02-01", "month of january"),
    (1, True, "2024-01-02", "2024-01-03", "subset of january"),
    (1, True, "2024-01-15", "2024-02-15", "mid-jan to mid-feb"),
    (1, True, "2024-03-01", "2024-04-01", "distinct date range")
]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["user", "is_relevant", "from_date", "to_date", "description"])

# Convert string dates to DateType
df = df.withColumn("start", col("from_date").cast(DateType())) \
       .withColumn("end", col("to_date").cast(DateType()))

# Filter only rows where is_relevant is True
df = df.where(col("is_relevant"))

df = (
    df.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("start", "end")))
    .withColumn(
        "previous_end",
        max(col("end")).over(
            Window.partitionBy("user")
            .orderBy("start", "end")
            .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow - 1)
        ),
    )
    .withColumn("island_start_indicator", when(col("previous_end") >= col("start"), lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1)))
    .withColumn("island_id", sum("island_start_indicator").over(Window.orderBy("start", "end")))
    .withColumn("island_min_start", min("start").over(Window.partitionBy('island_id')))
    .withColumn("island_max_end", max("end").over(Window.partitionBy('island_id')))
    .select('user', 'is_relevant', col('island_min_start').alias('start_date'), col('island_max_end').alias('end_date'))
    .dropDuplicates()
)

df.show()

+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|user|is_relevant|start_date|  end_date|
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|   1|       true|2024-01-01|2024-02-15|
|   1|       true|2024-03-01|2024-04-01|
+----+-----------+----------+----------+



Thanks! With a little tweaking I got this running :)

To achieve the result you're looking for, you need to merge the overlapping date ranges where is_relevant is true. This can be done efficiently in PySpark. Below is a step-by-step approach to merging overlapping intervals:

Sort and Collect the Data: First, collect the date ranges into a list sorted by from_date.
Merge Intervals: Iterate through the sorted list and merge overlapping or adjacent intervals.

Here's the PySpark code to accomplish this:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, collect_list, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

# Initialize Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MergeIntervals").getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [
    (1, True, "2024-01-01", "2024-02-01", "month of january"),
    (1, True, "2024-01-02", "2024-01-03", "subset of january"),
    (1, True, "2024-01-15", "2024-02-15", "mid-jan to mid-feb"),
    (1, True, "2024-03-01", "2024-04-01", "distinct date range")
]

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["user", "is_relevant", "from_date", "to_date", "description"])

# Convert string dates to DateType
df = df.withColumn("from_date", col("from_date").cast(DateType())) \
       .withColumn("to_date", col("to_date").cast(DateType()))

# Filter only rows where is_relevant is True
df = df.filter(col("is_relevant") == True)

# Collect and sort the intervals
intervals = df.select("from_date", "to_date").orderBy("from_date").collect()

# Function to merge overlapping intervals
def merge_intervals(intervals):
    merged = []
    for interval in intervals:
        if not merged or merged[-1][1] < interval[0]:
            merged.append(interval)
        else:
            merged[-1] = (merged[-1][0], max(merged[-1][1], interval[1]))
    return merged

# Apply the merge_intervals function
merged_intervals = merge_intervals([(row["from_date"], row["to_date"]) for row in intervals])

# Convert merged intervals back to DataFrame
merged_df = spark.createDataFrame(merged_intervals, ["from_date", "to_date"])

# Show the result
merged_df.show()

Explanation:

Data Preparation: Initialize a Spark session and create a DataFrame with the sample data.
Filter and Convert Date Columns: Filter the DataFrame to only include rows where is_relevant is True, and convert the date columns from strings to DateType.
Collect and Sort Intervals: Collect the date ranges into a list and sort them by from_date.
Merge Intervals: Define a function merge_intervals to merge overlapping or adjacent intervals. This function iterates over the sorted intervals and merges them if they overlap.
Create Merged DataFrame: Convert the merged intervals back to a DataFrame and display the result.

This solution ensures that overlapping and adjacent date ranges are merged, resulting in non-overlapping intervals that you can use to join back to your data without creating duplicate records.

Thanks to the above I managed to get this running in Spark SQL:
with source_data as (
    select
        group_key
        , thing_i_care_about
        , from_date
        , date_add(to_date, 1) as closed_to_date
    from my_table
)

, windowed as (
    select
        group_key
        , thing_i_care_about
        , from_date
        , closed_to_date
        , lag(closed_to_date) over group_window as previous_to_date
    from source_data
    window group_window as (
        partition by group_key, thing_i_care_about
        order by from_date, closed_to_date
    )
)

, islands as (
    select
        group_key
        , think_i_care_about
        , from_date
        , closed_to_date
        -- This is where the magic happens, I had to pen/paper this to be sure
        , sum(
            case when previous_to_date = from_date then 0 else 1 end
        ) over (
            partition by group_key, thing_i_care_about
            order by from_date, closed_to_date
            rows between unbounded preceding and 0 preceding
        ) as island_id
        , is_basic
    from windowed
)

select distinct
    group_key
    , thing_i_care_about
    , min(from_date) over w as island_min_start
    , max(closed_to_date) over w as island_max_end
from islands
window w as (
    partition by group_key, thing_i_care_about, island_id
)

Note: I needed to update to a closed to_date so that previous_to_date = from_date for the islands. I could have done a comparison to from_date - 1 but that felt uglier.
